# Понятие «концептуальная модель данных предметной области». Как понимать это?

Tags: машинное-обучение, распознавание-образов, модель-данных

Я пишу дипломную работу. При защите дипломной работы также нужна презентация. К требованиям этой презентации я вижу, что презентация должна включать описание **"концептуальной модели данных предметной области"**.

---

Моя дипломная работа посвящена **распознаванию образов**. А именно распознавание рукописного текста. Имеется программа, которая обучена распознавать рукописные буквы. На вход подается картинка с буквами и алгоритм производит распознавание. Используются разные алгоритмы. Но что я должен включить в описание концептуальной модели данных предметной области в моем случае? Я не совсем понимаю, что это понятие значит. Что по сути нужно описывать?

Comment: в любой задаче есть данные, они также обычно связаны между собой - согласитесь, странная была бы задача для которой это не так - знаете хоть одну такую? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Концептуальная модель данных предметной области - это описание сущностей и связей между ними.
Поскольку модель **концептуальная**, то не нужно приводить все атрибуты сущностей, достаточно ключевых.
Подробнее можете почитать здесь: [Модель сущность-связь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Из вашего описания сразу видно, что у вас будут сущности "картинка", "буква", "текст". По смыслу, возможно появление сущностей "слово", "предложение"...